# Gatsby API endpoint

Tags: reactjs, api, graphql, gatsby

I'm new to gatsby/graphql and I'm using the [gatsby-source-custom-api](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-custom-api/) plugin and based on the gatsby-config example:

```
// Lets assume this is the data from your API:
const exampleDataFromApi = [
    {
        url: "post-1",
        images: [
            {
                url: "image-1.jpg",
                modified: 1556752476267
            },
            {
                url: "image-2.jpg",
                modified: 1556752702168
            }
        ],
        author: {
            firstname: "John",
            lastname: "Doe"
        }
    }
];

// This is the content of your gatsby-config.js
// and what you need to provide as schema:
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-source-custom-api",
            options: {
                url: {
                    development: "http://my-local-api.dev", // on "gatsby develop"
                    production: "https://my-remote-api.com" // on "gatsby build"
                },
                imageKeys: ["images"],
                rootKey: "posts",
                schemas: {
                    posts: `
                        url: String
                        images: [images]
                        author: author
                    `,
                    images: `
                        url: String
                        modified: Int
                    `,
                    author: `
                        firstname: String
                        lastname: String
                    `
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

I was wondering if there's a way to change the endpoint of the API based on the current page? For example current URL is https://mywebsite.com/data1 and API endpoint https://my-remote-api.com/data1.

I'm trying to reproduce this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://my-remote-api.com/' + this.props.endpoint)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
}
```

but with graphql.